# Moving sqlite3 to mariadb for NPM (Nginx Proxy Manager)

Tags: docker, nginx, mariadb

I had a working NPM on one machine using docker.  Though I configured to used mariadb in the docker-compose, seems it used the sqlite to store all its credentials.  I noticed this only after I tried migrate to a new host.

After the migration, the NPM used mariadb.  I can see this from the startup log.  At this point, I was not able to log in using the old credentials.  I could use the default credentials which comes with NPM to login.  After login, all my previously configured web hosts are gone.  They still continue to work though.  Not sure how NPM achieves this.

I want to move all those hosts and SSL configs back.  For this I need to move the contents from sqlite to mariadb.  Has anyone tried this?  If yes then can you share some tips on how to achieve this?